# Discriminants of some $q$-analogs of $(1+x)^n$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, q-analogs, discriminant

Let $[n]_q=1+q+\dots +q^{n-1}$, $ {[n]_q}! =[1]_q [2]_q \dots [n]_q$  and $\binom{n}{j}_q = \frac{[n]_q!}{[j]_q![n-j]_q!}$ be the usual $q$-notation.

Consider the polynomials $p_n(q,r,x)= \sum_{j=0}^n q^{r\binom{j}{2}}\binom{n}{j}_qx^j$ and let $d_{n,r}(q)=\Delta_{x} p_n(q,r,x)$ be their [discriminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

The well-known identity $p_n(q,1,x) =(1+x)(1+qx)\dots(1+q^{n-1}x)$ implies that
$$d_{n,1}(q)=\Delta_{x} p_n(q,1,x)=(1-q)^{2\binom{n}{2}}q^{2\binom{n}{3}}\Big(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}[j]_q!\Big)^2.$$
This gives  $ d_{n,1}(q)=q^{n(n-1)^2} d_{n,1}(q^{-1}).$
Computations suggest that more generally the following holds for integers $r$:
$$ d_{n,1+r}(q)=q^{n(n-1)^2} d_{n,1-r}(q^{-1}).$$

> **QUESTION.** Is this a known result? If yes, where can I find it, if no, any idea how to prove it?

Comment: A naive question: why do you prefer the discriminant to a possible "$q$-discriminant": I would guess it to be the resultant of $f$ and its $q$-derivative $(f(qx)-f(x))/(qx-x)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true.

We have
\begin{align*} 
p_n (q^{-1}, 1-r, x) &= \sum_{j=0}^n q^{ (r-1) \binom{j}{2}}  \binom{n}{j}_{q^{-1}} x^j \\
&=  \sum_{j=0}^n q^{ (r-1) \binom{j}{2}}  q^{-j (n-j)} \binom{n}{j}_{q} x^j \\  
&=\sum_{j=0}^n q^{ (r+1) \binom{j}{2}}  q^{-j (n-j) - j (j-1)} \binom{n}{j}_{q} x^j \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n q^{ (r+1) \binom{j}{2}}  \binom{n}{j}_{q} (x q^{-(n-1)} )^j \\
&= p_n(q, 1+r, x q^{-(n-1)}).
\end{align*}

and changing variables $x \to \lambda x$ in a polynomial multiplies the discriminant by $\lambda^{ n (n-1)}$.